# 3rd Gen i3 vs 9th Gen i3?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i3

What's the difference between an Intel Core i3 3rd Gen processor (for example 3217u) and an Intel Core i3 9th Gen processor (for example 9320) in terms of how much percent faster, processor base frequency, cache, etc. in a relatively detailed explanation?

Comment: Have you tried to google this? What did dozens of sites that do CPU comparisons tell you?

Comment: I have tried googling it; It doesn't really appear on the internet, but if you have a good site recommendation answering this question, I'll take it. @gronostaj

Comment: Look here:  https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/processors/core/intel-core-i3-comparison-chart.pdf   Difference in Cache (more in 9th) and Threads (more in 9th). But it is still an i3 so do not expect it be fast. We do not specify anything less than i5 and that only for non-demanding office work.

Comment: There's Intel ARK, cpubenchmark.net, cpuboss.com... Anyway, this comparison doesn't make much sense because it's a laptop CPU vs. desktop CPU, desktop will always win because it's not focused on power efficiency.

Comment: Do my post and Intel link satisfy you?

Comment: Yes, they do. @John

Comment: You may post it as an answer for me to accept as. @John

Comment: Thank you and Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a comparison of Intel Processors by Generation, look here:

[Intel Core i3 Comparison Chart](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/processors/core/intel-core-i3-comparison-chart.pdf) Difference in Cache (more in 9th) and Threads (more in 9th).

[image: Intel Core i3 Desktop Processors Comparison Chart]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

but it is still an i3 so do not expect it be fast. We do not specify anything less than i5 and that only for non-demanding office work.